# Does + 1 really matter in the python function below?

Tags: python

I am new to programming and I'm taking a online course in python. I have a question to ask about a line in the below function:

```
def sum_first_n(n):
    result = 0
    for i in range(n):
        result += i + 1
    print(result)
sum_first_n(100)
```

The result is 5050. Now looking at line 4: result += i  + 1, if I remove the  + 1  from that line, I still get the same result. Can anyone kindly explain what the work of + 1 is or can it be omitted when writing?

Comment: In fact, you might be missing something about running your code. The results are not the same. When running without `+1` the answer is 4950, as expected.

Comment: That's true. My bad. I thought there was something wrong with adding +  1. Thanks Pedro.

Answer (score 1):

I removed +1 from the line, and it printed 4950. `+1` matters. Let me explain.
First, `result = 0`, nothing to do here. 
`for i in range(n)` means repeat n times, STARTING from `i=0` so it ends at `n=99`.
For each loop, `result = result + i + 1`. Since your loop only sums 100 times, it stops at `i=99`, but there's 100 `+1` so the result is 5050.
To make this code more readable, change it into `for i in range(n+1): result += i` means the loop starts at 0 and ends at 100, and that's your sum of the first 100 positive integer numbers.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks AerysS for the detailed explanation. Now I understand it better.

Comment: Hi, if my question solves your problem, please accept it to mark as answered. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

It will definitely make a difference in your output. First, when i is 0, the resulting integer has the value 1, for the next iteration of the loop, 2 will be added to the result so the result would equal 3.
Whereas if the incrementation by 1 didn't exist the value of the result would be 2 and so on.
So it will have an impact for sure!

Answer (score 0):

'result += i + 1' is the same as 'result = result + i + 1'.
'result = result + i + 1' leads to 5050 and 'result = result + i' leads to 4050.
Maybe you are missing any environment option.

Comment: Thanks KD2020. I probably didn't understand thhe function of + 1 in the code. I do now. Thanks